# How to use a c99 compiler on PC

Tags: c, codeblocks, c99

I have CodeBlocks 13.12 and I want to compile a c99 code on it. Is there any way I can do this. If there is any other way to compile a c99 code, that is okay as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Just about _any_ basic Code::Blocks tutorial will guide you through compiling a C or C++ program and familiarize you with the IDE. Beyond that, have you tried Googling “code::blocks compiler options”?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried Googling on how to use the c99 mode in version 13.12 of code blocks but almost all the answers I found were answered 5+ years ago and are no longer applicable for the latest version. Also, from the option of add new flag I added ``-std=c99``  in the tab for compiler flag (I didn't know what to add for Linker Flags, Category, Supersedes and Check Category) but I still have errors like unknown type name UINT16 and CPLX32.

Comment: I doubt the option to select C99 standard has changed a lot in the last decade. `UINT16` is not a standard type in C99. You probably need to include extra headers of some libraries. What kind of code do you want to compile? Where did you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the option of add new flag I added `-std=c99` in the tab for compiler flag and it works.